# Unit root test for a group of variables

Tags: stata

I want to perform unit root tests (ADF, DFGLS, KPSS) on a group of variables, say `X1, X2, X3, X4`. Is it possible to write code in Stata to perform the tests in one go for all variables? I tried using `foreach`, but was unsuccessful.

In a Stata do-file I tried:

```
foreach var of varlist lic lac ldc lcc {
    dfuller 'var'
}
```

where `lic, lac, ldc`, and `lcc` are variable names.

I am getting error message

> ' invalid name

Comment: Please show us the code you tried and why it doesn't work. Edit your question to include the relevant information.

Comment: Read the _Asking_ section in http://stackoverflow.com/help for guidelines on posting good questions.

Comment: dfuller 'var' should be dfuller `var'

Answer (score 0):

You are using incorrect quotes to (de)reference the local macro `var`. You should open with a backtick quote `` ` `` and close with a regular quote `'`. So it should be `` `var' ``. You have two regular quotes: `'var'`.

A reference is the manual: **[U] 18.3.1 Local macros**.